# What does Me.Invoke(string) do?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please explain this code to me

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.sfasfafssverket.se/webservice/BUMS/Seamen/SetPasswordForPersonalIdentit"& _ 
    "yNumber", RequestNamespace:="http://www.sjofaasddasdket.se/webservice/BUMS/Seamen/", ResponseNamespace:="http://www.sjasdasdverket.se/webservice/BUMS/Seamen/", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _
Public Function SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber(ByVal personalIdentityNumber As String, ByVal newPassword As Boolean, ByVal fromWeb As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber", New Object() {personalIdentityNumber, newPassword, fromWeb})
    Return CType(results(0),Boolean)
End Function
```

I'm trying to figure out the boolean `newPassword`. Where is the condition that determines if it's going to be true or false?

So that means I have to figure this out:

```
Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber", New Object() {personalIdentityNumber, newPassword, fromWeb})
```

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: `Invokes an XML Web service method synchronously using SOAP.` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). So in your case you call a WebService method named `SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber` and pass `personalIdentityNumber, newPassword, fromWeb` as parameters. The WebService returns a boolean result. `Me` is propably a generated Xml Web service proxy class.

Comment: So that would mean that the method `SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber` in the WebService can answer my question on what determines those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding Alex B's response in the comments as an answer.

> Invokes an XML Web service method synchronously using SOAP. MSDN. So
>   in your case you call a WebService method named
>   SetPasswordForPersonalIdentityNumber and pass personalIdentityNumber,
>   newPassword, fromWeb as parameters. The WebService returns a boolean
>   result. Me is propably a generated Xml Web service proxy class.

[Non-Foreign MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)